# href attribute breaking an element

Tags: html, css

Here is my html

```
  <a class="button special" href="http://secure.hostgator.com/~affiliat/cgi-bin/affiliates/clickthru.cgi?id=vpspricing&page=http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting">Select</a>
```

Some CSS--I don't think this is important but including anyway.

```
background-color: #449403;
box-shadow: none !important;
color: #FFF !important;
margin-left: 2px;
```

I've pinned it down to being the value in the href since http://www.google.com will work and various other URLs. My a element shows up in the inspect element but it does not show up in the gui and I have no idea why. Is there a character in there that I should be escaping?

Comment: `&page` should be `&amp;page`.

Comment: could you reproduce this in a fiddle?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/741pn99m/

Comment: try to remove your CSS little by little and see if you can track it down.  Maybe it's a :visited link style, that isn't applied on other random URLs you enter there?

Comment: Is the CSS you've shown the actual style that's applied to element when you inspect it?

Comment: Interesting question, how is this related to Javascript?

Comment: @Arbel your fiddle works in chrome but not in my FF. I wonder if something is just corrupt with my firefox browser. Does the fiddle posted work for anyone else in FF? I'm on FF 38.0.5

Comment: @Konnor It works in FF too, v. 38.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarrassing but my adblocker was blocking the link...

Answer (score 1):

Try URL-encoding the query string. You can use the `encodeURI` JavaScript function

Answer (score 1):

The URL should be HTML encoded, and the query string values should be URL encoded.

The `&` should be HTML encoded as `&amp;`, and `:` and `/` in the values should be URL encoded as `%3A` and `%2F`:

```
href="http://secure.hostgator.com/~affiliat/cgi-bin/affiliates/clickthru.cgi?id=vpspricing&amp;page=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hostgator.com%2Fvps-hosting"
```

Breakdown: First the values `vpspricing` and `http://www.hostgator.com/vps-hosting` are URL encoded into `vpspricing` (no change) and `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hostgator.com%2Fvps-hosting` so that you can put them in the URL. Then you HTML encode the entire URL so that you can put it in the attribute in the HTML code. It's only the `&` character that needs to be HTML encoded in this case.